# Detect variable value change in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I've got node running on my raspberry pi, and when you press a button, `rpio.read(22)` will return 0 instead of 1.

I would like to detect when this happens, and trigger a function from it. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this right now would be to continually loop until the value of `rpio.read(22)` changes. 
It's not very elegant, but you could just do something like this:

```
function buttonCheck(){
    if (rpio.read(22) == 0) {
        // code here
    } else {
        process.nextTick(buttonCheck);
    }
}
```